# WCF REST Service : Allowing Cross Domain Access

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I am hosting a RESTful WCF service in an azure Web Role.
This service is to be consumed by jQuery.

How do I allow cross domain access to this service?

Thanks

Comment: On your binding element you would have a property "crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled" which needs to be set to true and also when making a call from JQuery make sure to set the dataType to JSONP

Comment: JSONP is not an option as the jQuery client will not only be issuing GET requests.

Ideally I would like to implement CORS in my WCF service, but I dont see how to do that

Comment: Isn't possible to use a cross domain policy file?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I just came across a similar issue and thought the following may help someone stumbling across this question. In visual studio, add a new xml file called `clientaccesspolicy.xml` to your Web Role project with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="SOAPAction">
        <domain uri="*"/>
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

To restrict access, edit the `<domain uri="*"/>` to whatever you need to.